# Sum of field in a consecutive period based on a condition

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-orm

I did this without complicated query and with Python. But I'm looking for a way to do this with `Django ORM`.

I have a table as follows:

| user | date | point |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | 2022/01/04 | 13 |
| John | 2022/01/04 | 10 |
| Mary | 2022/01/03 | 0 |
| John | 2022/01/03 | 5 |
| Mary | 2022/01/01 | 1 |
| John | 2022/01/01 | 1 |
| Mary | 2021/12/31 | 5 |

I want to calculate the `Sum` of `point`s from `now()` to the `date` when the point value is ***greater than one***.

**Desired Output:**

| user | sum |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mary | 14 | `13+1` |
| John | 10 | `10` |

Comment: Try this: `Model.objects.filter(date__gte=timezone.now(), point__gt=1).values('user').annotate(sum=Sum('point'))`

Comment: @BrianDestura I think op wants to stop when the sum becomes greater than 1. It's not completely clear from the description of the question why the sum of Mary is 14 and not 13 or 19.

Comment: @VishalSingh This is exactly what I want

Comment: @Saeed can you explain why the sum of mary is not 13 because if you order by date the first point is 13 which is greater than 1.

Comment: @VishalSingh Because it was 0 and 1 in the previous two dates (`2022/01/03` and `2022/01/01`). So they add with 13. But the pre - dated (`2021/12/31`) was 5 
and it is more than one, it does not accumulate with 13